# Showing that a set is an interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For my Measure & Integration course I was working on the following problem:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f: \Omega \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ be a measurable function. Show that the set $\{p \in [1,\infty): f \in \mathcal{L}^p(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)\}$ is an interval.
Unfortunately I got stuck on this question. Could somebody help me to prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $f \in \mathcal{L}^p(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and $f \in \mathcal{L}^q(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ for some $p \le q$. Let's prove that $f \in \mathcal{L}^r(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ for all $p \le r \le q$.

Let's denote $S = \{x \in \Omega: |f(x)| \le 1\}$ and $Q = \Omega \setminus S$. Then $$\int\limits_{\Omega}|f|^r d\mu = \int\limits_{S}|f|^r d\mu + \int\limits_{Q}|f|^r d\mu \le \int\limits_{S}|f|^p d\mu + \int\limits_{Q}|f|^q d\mu \le ||f||_p^p + ||f||_q^q < \infty$$
Therefore $f \in \mathcal{L}^r(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$.

Note that if $f \in \mathcal{L}^p(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ for some $p > 1$ then $f$ may not belong to $\mathcal{L}^q(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ for $q < p$ if measure is not finite. For example $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + |x|}$ belongs to $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ but does not belong to $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$. If measure is finite you can estimate integral $\int\limits_{S}|f|^p d\mu$ in the inequality by $\mu(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got a hint from somebody that what I tried was not the right way to solve the exercise. Thanks for the effort.